# Create a table from Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryResult using fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I'm using typo3 and learning how it works. I'm trying to build a table with some pictures, but all that I have tried didn't work. So I will like to have some suggestions about how this can be accomplished.

Here is what I have:

On my controller I get a [Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryResult](http://doxygen.frozenkiwi.com/typo3/html/d5/dd7/QueryResult_8php_source.html) with a group of pictures:

```
$fileElements = $fileElementRepository->getFileElementsByNumberOf($id,     $numberOfElements);

$this->view->assign('fileElements', $fileElements);
```

And here is what I do with them on my index.html:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <f:for each="{fileElements}" as="satArc">
<td>
   <f:image src="{satArc.filePath}" alt="{satArc.linkText}" />
</td>
  </f:for>
```

At the moment I get a row with all the pictures available. Because I have the for loop inside the  tag. But I would like to find a way to group them in rows with 4 pictures. But I haven't figure it out how to divide in groups of 4 elements the queryResult.

I hope this is clear enough, otherwise ask.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Have a look at the for loop's iteration argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<f:for each="{...}" as="...">
    <f:cycle values="{0:'', 1:'', 2:'', 3:1}" as="isLast">
       <f:if condition="{isLast} == 1">...</f:if>
   </f:cycle>
</f:for>
```

So you can close the row and start a new one.